# .NET Chart and Bar Charts

Tags: c#, .net, charts

I have some code running but the scales are wrong. I have tried a lot of variations and nothing is properly working. I googled this and a lot of third party plugins for graphs which people are using. Any tips are welcome. I am using MVC 3 and .NET/C#.

```
int userID = da.getUserID(username);
int shopid = da.getShopID(brandnamelist[0].ToString());
BaseController db = new BaseController();
DataSet retailerManDS = da.getRetailerManDS(db, shopid);

String[] retailerArray = new String[retailerManDS.Tables[0].Rows.Count];
int[] bestPriceArray = new int[retailerManDS.Tables[0].Rows.Count];

for (int i = 0; i < retailerManDS.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
{
    String retailername = retailerManDS.Tables[0].Rows[i]["RetailerName"].ToString();
    int numberBestPrices = Convert.ToInt32(
        retailerManDS.Tables[0].Rows[i]["numberBestPrices"]);
    retailerArray[i] = retailername;
    bestPriceArray[i] = numberBestPrices;
}

var key = new Chart(width: 800, height: 800)
   .AddTitle(brandnamelist[0].ToString()+ " Best Prices")
   .AddSeries(
     chartType: "StackedBar",
     name: "Best Prices",
     markerStep: 1,
     xValue: retailerArray,
     xField: "Retailers",
     yValues: bestPriceArray,
     yFields: "Number Best Prices");

byte[] byteImage = key.ToWebImage().GetBytes();
string imageBase64Data = Convert.ToBase64String(byteImage);
string imageDataUrl = string.Format("data:image/jpeg;base64,{0}", imageBase64Data);
charts.chart = imageDataUrl;
```

This code actually produces a graph and all the visuals are correct. But the it misses out the labels on the x axis. It seems to divide up the xaxis into 4 parts and label them and then show all the bars (there are 11). Hence 7 bars have no label on them.

I had hardcoded the arrays and it works, and hence the error is related to substituting the `new[] { "...", "..."}` with a variable for the array. I assume this is somehow related to type but I cannot get to the cause of the error.

I am not using a thirdparty plugin.

Comment: The last line should read "I am not using a third party plugin" - typo.

Comment: You may freely edit your question to fix that typo. While you're at it, you could fix the indentation of your code so it's a little more readable. Not much, mind. It's almost there.

Comment: Have you used the debugger to look into the arrays after the loop?

Comment: Yes the loop is all fine and the data is OK. This is related to IEnumerable which I am just testing now.

Comment: I would encourage you to deep dive into Microsoft chart controls: they come with a huge amount of excellent samples and may be used with asp.Net mvc. Better to use something that seamlessly integrates than redo it. A few links: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/125230/ASP-NET-MVC-Chart-Control and http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/092210-1.aspx

Comment: Did I miss something? Doesn't he use Chart already??

Comment: OK the comment worked about the codeproject.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the code suggested in the comment and the code all worked. I added the following

```
 using System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting;
```

and the rest of the code is as shown at the link - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/125230/ASP-NET-MVC-Chart-Control